# How to loop based on the value of Arraylist integer

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have one arraylist integer that contain the number of row like this:

```
[2, 9, 16, 23, 30, 37, 44, 51, 58, 65, 72, 79]
```

Now, I want to set the color on certain row based on the number from the arraylist like this:

```
      for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
            for (int p = SA.get(0); p < SA.size() + 1; p = SA.get(p)) {
                XSSFRow SATURDAY = sheet.getRow(p);
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    if (SATURDAY.getCell(i) != null) {
                        SATURDAY.getCell(i).setCellStyle(greycolor);
                    } else {
                        Cell cell1 = SATURDAY.createCell(i);
                        cell1.setCellStyle(greycolor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is, when I run the class file, it only set the color of row number 2 and number 16. the rest of the row are not affected. I don't know how to do the increment for looping the arraylist. help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating incorrectly.
You initialize `p` to `SA.get(0)`, which is `2`. Then you change it to `SA.get(p)` (i.e. `SA.get(2)`), which is `16`. Then you exit the loop, since `16 > SA.size() + 1`.

Try :

```
for (int p : SA) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
for (int x = 0; x < SA.length; x++) {
    int p = SA.get(x);
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh my lord. that simple. Thank you Sir for helping me.